# How to manage weak and strong function in c

Tags: c

I have weak and strong "_write" functions in my project. Library A should use weak _write and library B should use strong _write. So I used a compiler flag (ENABLE_FOR_LIBB) in the strong _write to protect it.

ie.
When library B is initialized, I will set the compiler flag. So that the strong _write function is enabled/compiled and it will get used.
Otherwise, the strong _write function will not be compiled. So library A will by default use weak _write.

I am trying to find a way to manage the weak and strong functions dynamically. Basically, I don't want to use a compiler flag to manage the weak and strong functions. When library A is initialized, the compiler should pick the weak function. If B is initialized, the compiler should pick the strong function.  Is there any method to manage it? Please share your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: where is your [mcve]?

Comment: why not use #define and #ifndef ?

Comment: @Ertugrul if you distribute library in the binary form you cant use it